# How to implement the progress bar correctly with wxPython

Tags: wxpython, progress-bar

I'm using the progress bar to inform a user as to the progress of completing a file search. When implementing this, it seemed like the most logical choice at the time, to get the number of files to be searched, then create a range based on that number, and progress according to files that have been searched. It seemed to work, but now I'm noticing that the progress bar is maxing out before the file search is complete. I'm a Python neophyte, so any and all suggestions on how I can make this more efficient is welcomed.

Below is my code:

```
    ...

    self.progress_bar = wx.Gauge(self.statusbar, -1, style=wx.GA_HORIZONTAL|wx.GA_SMOOTH)
    rect = self.statusbar.GetFieldRect(2)
    self.progress_bar.SetPosition((rect.x+2, rect.y+2))
    self.progress_bar.SetSize((rect.width-3, rect.height-4))

    self.progress_bar.Hide()

    ...


    count = 0
    count2 = 0
    for afile in filelist:
        (head, filename) = os.path.split(afile)
        if afile.endswith(".log") or afile.endswith(".txt"):
            count2 += 1
            self.progress_bar.Show()
            self.progress_bar.SetRange(numFiles)
            wx.CallAfter(self.progress_bar.SetValue, count2)
            f=ftp.open(afile, 'r')
            for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
                result = regex.search(line)
                if self.shouldAbort:
                    return self.shouldAbort
                    break
```

Comment: I think you're doing it right. Does it max out right before it's done? That might be a timing issue or an off-by-one issue. You should consider cross-posting to the wxPython mailing list too.

Comment: @Mike Driscoll Actually, it maxes out about 20-30 seconds before it's done.

Comment: maybe you need to put some logging or print statements in to see what's going on. Does the printing of the file names correspond to the progress dialog's updates? If not, something is going on in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it this way:

```
count = 0
count2 = 0
self.progress_bar.Show()
self.progress_bar.SetRange(len(filelist)
for afile in filelist:
    (head, filename) = os.path.split(afile)
    if afile.endswith(".log") or afile.endswith(".txt"):
        f=ftp.open(afile, 'r')
        for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
            result = regex.search(line)
            if self.shouldAbort:
                return self.shouldAbort
                break
    count2 += 1
    self.progress_bar.SetValue(count2)
```